# Cannot open image download from S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm using S3 to store image files with below code. Because image is can't public so I use preSignUrl to provide 1 authenticated URL with expire time. Everything worked, but when I click to `getUrl` and open the download file, macOS show error as image:

```
const {
  S3Client,
  PutObjectCommand,
  DeleteObjectCommand,
  DeleteObjectsCommand,
  GetObjectCommand,
} = require('@aws-sdk/client-s3');
const awsPresigner = require('@aws-sdk/s3-request-presigner');

const getCommand = (fileNames, action) => {
  let ObjectCommand;
  const params = {
    Bucket: process.env.STORAGE_EVENT_S3_BUCKET,
    Key: fileNames,
  };
  switch (action) {
    case 'put': {
      ObjectCommand = PutObjectCommand;
      break;
    }

    case 'delete': {
      ObjectCommand = DeleteObjectCommand;
      break;
    }

    case 'deleteMany': {
      ObjectCommand = DeleteObjectsCommand;
      params.Delete = {
        Objects: params.Key.map((key) => ({ Key: key })),
      };
      delete params.Key;
      break;
    }

    default: {
      ObjectCommand = GetObjectCommand;
      break;
    }
  }

  const command = new ObjectCommand(params);

  return command;
};

const getPresignedUrl = (fileName, action) => {
  const command = getCommand(fileName, action);

  const s3Client = new S3Client({
    credentials: {
      accessKeyId: process.env.AWS_PUBLIC_KEY,
      secretAccessKey: process.env.AWS_PRIVATE_KEY,
    },
    region: process.env.AWS_REGION,
  });

  return awsPresigner.getSignedUrl(s3Client, command, {
    expiresIn: 60 * 60,
  });
};

const run = async () => {
  const putUrl = await getPresignedUrl('a/b.png', 'put');

  const getUrl = await getPresignedUrl('a/b.png', 'get');

  console.log(putUrl, '\n', getUrl)
}

run();
```

[image]

Comment: Your code has PNG files but your browser seems to be receiving a file with JPG extension.

Comment: @jarmod actually, it's 2 testing times, I tried change extension file (png -> jpg ) in code and re-testing  with jpg image, that's why in my acttach file is .jpg.